# How to run a macro with a dynamic list

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu, wait

Right now I have multiple macros set up and I would like to cut it down to one. First the user inputs the desired part number they are looking for and the macro will return the all the different versions associated with that part number in a dropdown. Next the user will go and select the version from the dropdown that they want to look at and the next macro will find the name associated with it.

Is there a way for the macro to wait until user has entered a value then continue to execute code again?

THIS IS THE FIRST MACRO

```
Dim part As String


Application.ScreenUpdating = False


'Filter based on user entry
Sheets("New Revision ").Select
    part = Range("B4").Value
    Sheets("PN_List").Select
    Columns("D:E").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$K$3000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=part

'Take current version and filter it to bottom of the list
  ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PN_List").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PN_List").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
        Range("E1:E3000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
        :=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PN_List").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With



'Version Number
Worksheets("PN_List").Activate
Range("B1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("table_converter").Visible = True
Sheets("table_converter").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("A1", Selection.End(xlDown)), xlNo).Name = _
        "master"
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("master").ShowHeaders = False
   Range("master[#All]").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="converter", RefersToR1C1:= _
        "=master[#All]"
    ActiveWorkbook.Names("converter").Comment = ""
     'ActiveSheet.ListObjects("master").ShowHeaders = False



'Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    'Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    'val = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Value

Worksheets("New Revision ").Activate
'Range("B7").Select
 '   With Selection.Validation
  '     .Delete
   '    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    '    xlBetween, Formula1:=r
     '  .IgnoreBlank = True
      ' .InCellDropdown = True
       '.InputTitle = ""
       '.ErrorTitle = ""
       '.InputMessage = ""
        '.ErrorMessage = ""
        '.ShowInput = True
        '.ShowError = True
    'End With



'Return PN_List to normal form
    Worksheets("PN_List").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$K$3000").AutoFilter Field:=1
    Columns("A:K").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PN_List").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PN_List").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "A2:A3000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PN_List").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "E2:E3000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PN_List").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:K3000")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Selection.AutoFilter


'hide key colunm
Worksheets("PN_List").Activate
Columns("D:E").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Range("A1").Select
  Worksheets("New Revision ").Activate

  Sheets("table_converter").Visible = False

  'Entry does not exsit
 ' If Worksheets("New Revision ").Range("B4") = "" Then
  'MsgBox "Part Number Not found. Please refer to the PN List.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Entry Error"
  'End If

 ' If Worksheets("New Revision ").Range("B6") = "" Then
 'Worksheets("New Revision ").Range("B4").ClearContents
 'End If
End Sub
```

HERE IS THE SECOND MACRO

```
Dim ver_num As String
    Dim prt_num As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Clear Previous Data in Search Version Number
      Sheets("table_converter").Visible = True
      Sheets("table_converter").Select
      Columns("A:A").Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        On Error Resume Next
         ActiveWorkbook.Names("converter").Delete

    'Retrun Part Name
    Sheets("New Revision ").Select
    Range("B4").Select
    ver_num = Selection.Value
    Range("B6").Select
    prt_num = Selection.Value
    Sheets("PN_List").Select

    'Find part name
     ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$K$3000").AutoFilter Field:=1
     ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$K$3000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=ver_num
     ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$K$3000").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=prt_num
    Range("F1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 0).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("New Revision ").Select
    Range("B8").Select
    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial
    With Selection
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
            .WrapText = False
            .Orientation = 0
            .AddIndent = False
            .IndentLevel = 0
            .ShrinkToFit = False
            .ReadingOrder = xlContext
            .MergeCells = False
        End With
        Selection.Font.Bold = True
        With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 15773696
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With

    'Filter List back to normal
         Sheets("PN_List").Select
         Columns("D:E").Select
        Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
         Selection.AutoFilter
        Columns("A:A").Select
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PN_List").Sort.SortFields.Clear
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PN_List").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
            "A2:A3000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
            xlSortNormal
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PN_List").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
            "E2:E3000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
            xlSortNormal
        With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PN_List").Sort
            .SetRange Range("A1:L3000")
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
    Columns("D:E").Select
        Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Range("A1").Select
        Sheets("New Revision ").Select
        With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
            .LineStyle = xlDouble
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThick
        End With
        Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
        Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone

    Sheets("table_converter").Visible = False

    End Sub
```

Comment: Sounds like a form would really help with this. The user could enter the 2 numbers (or select them from drop downs?) and the form could instantly generate / filter the list of versions.

Comment: Where are the values in B4 and B6 coming from? Is there data validation in those cells? And it looks like those selections drive everything else?

Comment: B4 is a cell that the user will enter the part number in. Once they execute the macro ,it will filter the list based on what the user has entered

Answer (score 0):

Something like `value = Inputbox("Input a value : ")` ?

**Edit:** *To detail on that,* you could do something like

```
Sub valueMenu()

    myValue = InputBox("Input a value : ")
    If myValue = 1 Then
        'Call Macro1
        Macro1
    ElseIf myValue = 2 Then
        'Call Macro2
        Macro2
    End If

End Sub

Sub Macro1()
    'Do something
End Sub

Sub Macro2()
    'Do something else
End Sub
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: "Is there a way for the macro to wait until user has entered a value then continue to execute code again." is pretty much textbook inputbox. Why is it wrong to provide it as an answer? Is it because I formulated my answer as a question only to point out the unclear nature of the OP?

Comment: No don't worry I am trying to get as much input as I can on this. So value = Inputbox("Input a value : ") how would I use this to take my 2 macros and combine them into one

Comment: Well, you said, and I quote : "Is there a way for the macro to wait until user has entered a value then continue to execute code again". The line of code I provided is specifically aimed at the only clear-cut question in your post.

Comment: Sorry your original answer before you edited was not a clear-cut answer. To someone that is fairly new at VBA I did not know how to implement that in my macro.

Comment: Please note that I said "clear-cut question", whereas you turned it around and said "clear-cut answer". My answer still isn't clear-cut (and never was intended to be), as it'd be pretty foolish to provide a clear-cut answer to such a vague "problem".